# Impossible to access a key "raisonSociale" on an object of class that does not implement ArrayAccess interface

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to access to my object using another value's object and I get this error

> Impossible to access a key "raisonSociale" on an object of class "XX\XXX\XX\" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface in XXBundle:XXX:list.html.twig at line 52.

```
{% for itemOrg in listOrganismeFav   %}

<td>
     {% for itemChamp in listChampTableOrgGest   %}

                   <a href="#">{{ itemOrg[itemChamp.champ] }}</a>

    {% endfor  %} 
</td>
{% endfor  %}
```

Could you help me ?

It's good it was because I used an object and I want to access it like a array.

Comment: you can implement ArrayAccess, see example: https://jeremycook.ca/2012/01/22/implementing-the-arrayaccess-interface/

Comment: Is `itemOrg` an Entity? Can you show the Entity code please. There's probably an easier way that what you are trying.

Comment: itemOrg is an entity and itemChamp is an entity too, there is no relation between them. itemOrg look like this: name, firstname, adress... itemChamp it's favorites information of itemOrg. in itemChamp I have just name and firstname so I don't want to show adress in my table. I did that and it's working very well :     {% for itemChamp in listChampTableOrgGest   %}
         {% if itemOrg[itemChamp.champ] is defined %}
  <td>
      <a href="#">{{ itemOrg[itemChamp.champ] }}</a>
  </td>       
     {% endif  %}
    {% endfor  %}
</tr>
{% endfor  %}